# Linq portability

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a tool to port linq expressions to regular foreach loops..?
If I were (say) to port existing linq driven code to an iPhone app?

Is this a problem since i use linq heavily?

Comment: There are libraries that reimplement LINQ for .NET 2.0, but other than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Resharper can change LINQ to loops.

Comment: LINQ Expressions can contain so much more than a simple predicate for interating over a set of items. are you solely want to translate simple wheres here or you want something real?

Comment: Change it to match the original expression, make it slower, faster? @Peter, it would be cool if such a tool could do everything that the expression does. Under the expression it's still loops and whiles is it true?

Comment: What sort of iPhone app are you writing? Are you using MonoTouch? If so, doesn't that support LINQ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet This is awesome, never knew it existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specialized in `Mono` development, but as much as I read it supports a `LINQ`. So you no need to translate your LINQ queries into the `for` loops.

[What .NET features does MonoTouch support?](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/topics/60472-ios-faq/articles) (LINQ with some limitations)

[MonoTouch 4 announcment](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Apr-06.html)